# How to maintain the glow effect of a json model rotating in three.js scene?

Tags: three.js, glow, shadermaterial

I add a json model with glow effect into the scene.

As follows:
[image]

I try to rotate the json model automatically.
However, it looks weird when it is rotating.
The glow effect of the model does not work.
[image]
[image]

I assume that the position of the json model does not be changed when this model is rotating. As the result, the viewVector.value of the ShaderMaterial is constant when this model is rotating(I do not change position of the camera).

```
if(jsonMesh){
    jsonMesh.rotation.y += 0.1;
    jsonMesh.material.uniforms.viewVector.value =
        new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( camera.position, jsonMesh.position );

}
```

This is the Three.ShaderMaterial.

VertexShader and  FragmentShader

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    uniform vec3 viewVector;
    uniform float c;
    uniform float p;
    varying float intensity;
    void main()
    {
        vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
        vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
        intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment"> 
    uniform vec3 glowColor;
    varying float intensity;
    void main() 
    {
        vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
        gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
    }
</script>
```

Three.ShaderMaterial.

```
var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( 
{
    uniforms: 
    { 
        "c":   { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        "p":   { type: "f", value: 1.4 },
        glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffff00) },
        viewVector: { type: "v3", value: camera.position }
    },
    vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader'   ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
}
);
```

How should I modify the code in this case?
Here is the [Demo](https://iceleaf97.github.io/QandA/ShaderGlow/ShaderGlow2.html) and [source code](https://github.com/iceleaf97/QandA/blob/master/ShaderGlow/ShaderGlow2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built in three.js functions for this. Instead of using the camera position, I chose to show you how to set a light source position in the world. That way you can match the light source on your custom shader to any light sources you plan to add later to your 3d world. Feel free to change the worldLightPoint value to camera.position instead of new THREE.Vector3(100,100,100). and in that case the effect will remain constant with the camera position.

```
var v = new THREE.Vector3();
//var worldLightPoint =  camera.position;
var worldLightPoint = new THREE.Vector3(100,100,100);
function update()
{
    controls.update();
    stats.update();
    if(jsonMesh){
        jsonMesh.rotation.y += 0.1;
        jsonMesh.material.uniforms.viewVector.value = jsonMesh.worldToLocal(v.copy(worldLightPoint));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Do not call `new` or `clone()` in the animation loop. Create an instance and reuse it. Use `copy()`.

Comment: @WestLangley Changed per recommendation, as I understand it.

Comment: Granted, there is no "right way", but I would use this pattern: `viewVector.value.copy( v )`. It is up to you. :-)

Comment: @WestLangley  Makes total sense. Your way is less calls in our calls, when we call our calls. :)

Comment: Thank you all !  It does work!! Actually I still do not know what "worldToLocal" means. But I will try my best to understand how to use ".worldToLocal()". Thank you so much. This is an amazing solution!

Comment: Every object has its own cartesian space. The world has its cartesian space. When you rotate the obejct, the world's space is not affected. The camera exists in world space. The shader exists in the object's space. You need to translate the  world position of the camera to the local cartesian space of the object.